# How to integer an oembed javascript tag inside a VueJs component?

Tags: vue.js, script-tag, oembed

I have an "embed" field used by my users for transform a simple link to a rich content link (link with image, title, description, etc.).

Example:
[image]

Note: I use this library to get all link information: [oscarotero/Embed](https://oscarotero.com/embed/demo/index.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FTomJamesSlade%2Fstatus%2F1315781356023173120)

As you can see, when you provide an url (a twitter tweet by example), the "code" parameter contain the HTML **and script tags** to include on my frontend:

```html
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">I am so hopelessly in love with <a href="https://twitter.com/ChucklefishLTD?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@ChucklefishLTD</a> ‘s spooky logo <a href="https://twitter.com/TomJamesSlade/status/1315781356023173120">pic.twitter.com/2KtjCNOOUl</a></p>&mdash; Tom Slayed  (@TomJamesSlade) <a href="https://twitter.com/TomJamesSlade/status/1315781356023173120?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">October 12, 2020</a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The problem is with VueJs and the script tag. When my ajax call is OK, I store all embed informations like that:

```
this.preview = response.embed
```

And inside my component, I display the html code with the "v-html" VueJs directive

```html
<div v-if="preview['code']" v-html="preview['code']"></div>
```

The html is displayed :

[image]

The script tag is visible inside the code inspector :

[image]

But the script is not loaded :

I have the same problem with all oembed url who provide a javascript tag inside the response.

Note: If I try to load the script directly inside the component, VueJs return this error:

> VueCompilerError: Tags with side effect ( and ) are ignored in client component templates

A solution on google is to use the "mounted" event, but it's not compatible with my context.
Because the script I have to load is received from an api and can be different each time depending of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's bit late but here is an option: The api gives you the possibility to not send the script tag, so you can include it on your own in the html before. Add to the url a `omit_script=true` and it's gone in the result.

Then you can insert the twitter block. Maybe you have to call `twttr.widgets.load()` to initialize the tweet.

Edit: Since you're using the plugin, this should be working

```
$embed = new Embed();

$result = $embed->get('https://www.instagram.com/p/B_C0wheCa4V/');
$result->setSettings([
    'oembed:query_parameters' => ['omit_script' => true]
]);
$oembed = $info->getOEmbed();
```